# Using sharedPreferences with a material spinner to update activities

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, android-sharedpreferences

I found this amazing Material spinner online and I was able to modify it for my code:

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:ms_multiline="false"
        app:ms_baseColor="@color/off"
        app:ms_highlightColor="@color/off"
        app:ms_hintColor="@color/off"
        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/off"
        app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
        app:ms_alignLabels="false"
        app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/off"/>
```

so I used sharedPreferences to store whatever value the user chooses from the spinner so when this page is called again, the choice is on the spinner face.
This is how I add the preferences in the onCreate:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

String[] ITEMS = {"Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ITEMS);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner = (MaterialSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setError(null);

spinpref=getSharedPreferences("frequency", MODE_PRIVATE);
            spinedit=spinpref.edit();
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (position == 1) {
                        int freq1 = 1;
                        spinedit.putInt("freq", freq1);
                        spinedit.apply();
                    } else if (position == 2) {
                        int freq2 = 2;
                        spinedit.putInt("freq", freq2);
                        spinedit.apply();
                    } else if (position == 3) {
                        int freq3=3;
                        spinedit.putInt("freq", freq3);
                        spinedit.apply();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    int freq0 = 0;
                    spinedit.putInt("freq", freq0);
                    spinedit.apply();
                }

            });
            finish();
}
```

then in the onResume, I do this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    spinpref=getSharedPreferences("frequency",MODE_PRIVATE);
    int num=spinpref.getInt("freq", 0);
    spinner.setSelection(num);
}
```

But my spinner just shows the first value, how could I do this to make it work? I don't think the sharedPrefs is wrong, but it may be the onItemSelected() and i'm not sure how else I could do this? 
PS: I tried replacing this line for each of the positions as

```
spinedit.putInt("freq", position);
```

instead of what I have there right now:

```
spinedit.putInt("freq", freq);
```

but that didn't work either.
Any ideas or material anyone is willing to bring to light for me please? I would appreciate it very much

Comment: Where are you setting the spinner adapter? You have to set it before the setSelection(). Is the value being saved correctly in the SharedPreferences? Also, have you tried using spinner.setSelection(num, false) ?

Comment: i have edited my code so you see how i set my adapter. Also, isn't the last line you suggested in your answer a getString from sharedPrefs? I put the num to that, so shouldn't it assume the number in the pref?

Comment: Just to narrow down the issue: have you tried logging the num variable (check if it is the correct index) and/or passing a 1or 2 int in setSelection(check if the problem is when updating the spinner)in the onResume() method? If so, what were the results of that?

Comment: omg its not saving it! when it did that, the value was 0!

Comment: Ok, just as i thought, try setting your value before attaching the setOnItemSelectedListener. I presume the onNothingSelected is being fired and saving the value as 0, try removing that piece of code and test it just to confirm

Comment: what piece do i take out?

Comment: What I mean: do a test without saving the freq value in onNothingSelected() and check the num value. If that works, then the onNothingSelected() code is the problem, it means it is being fired before the onResume() method and changing the freq in sharedpreferences

Comment: ok i removed all the code from onNothingSelected but it still gives zero

Comment: Weird, what option are you selecting? Btw, why is there a finish(); at the end of onCreate()?

Comment: i tried with all three items, also I added the finish() because when the user clicks save in that activity, it closes to go to another. could that be a problem?

Comment: Ok, try doing this: log the value of freq 'spinpref.getInt("freq",-1)',  just after calling apply(). Next try the same using commit() instead of apply()

Comment: oh wow, it prints nothing, not even zero

Comment: Try logging any data outside the if statement in onItemSelected(). Can you share your whole onCreate() method? The spinner you are modifying is the one in this activity view, right?  I want to believe that finish() is inside another method and not just lying there at the end of onCreate(), right? try removing it and see what happens :)

Comment: I have edited the question to add my opening and closing of oncreate(). also, i tried it with and without the finish() and it still did the same thing :(

Comment: Did you tried logging something from onItemSelected()?

Comment: i commented out the if/else statements and put a log and it does print something

Comment: try saving freq with any value outside the if/else and try the same using commit() instead of apply(). Save the spinedit as a property of your class (outside the onCreate), initialize it in onCreate and use it in onResume() and the listener.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm proposing (in my comment above):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences spinpref;
    Editor spinedit;

    //PREVENT TYPOS
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "frequency";
    public static final String FREQUENCY = "freq";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        //INIT PREFS
        spinpref=getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
        spinedit=spinpref.edit();

        //INIT SPINNER
        ...

        //SET LISTENER
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        int num=spinpref.getInt(FREQUENCY, 0);
        spinner.setSelection(num);
    }

}
```

Comment: mine is set up this way too, but how would you do your listener and spinner?

Comment: The same as you, the listener is being fired, so the problem seems to be that something is not initilized when the listener methods fire (hence declaring the spinpref and spinedit outside the onCreate()). Did you tried saving the prefs outisde the if/else statement?

Comment: but my prefs is supposed to get the integer by the position selected, how could i do it outside if/else?

Comment: Is just to check if the prefs are being saved or not. If they're, you need to debug that if/else statement